# LangChainを使ったアプリ開発のためのOpenAIをインストールしましたが、エラーが出ます。どのように解決したらよいですか？

Tags: python

下記のコードを入力すると下記のように出ました。
ご教授いただけると幸いです。

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
You tried to access openai.Completion, but this is no longer
supported in openai>=1.0.0 - see the README at
https://github.com/openai/openai-python for the API.

You can run `openai migrate` to automatically upgrade your codebase to
use the 1.0.0 interface. 

Alternatively, you can pin your installation to the old version, e.g.
`pip install openai==0.28`

A detailed migration guide is available here:
https://github.com/openai/openai-python/discussions/742
```

**コード:**

```
import os
import openai

os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = "XXXXXXXXXXXXX"

response = openai.Completion.create(
    model = "gpt-3.5-turbo",
    message = [
        {"role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful assistant."},
        {"role": "user", "content": "Who won the 2020 NBA finals?"},
    ]
)

print(response)
```

Comment: エラーメッセージで説明されているように見えますが、読んだうえで分からないですか？ / インストールされている openai モジュールのバージョンを確認してみてください。